# Euler angles to ENU coordinates

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, angle, spherical-coordinates, orientation

Given the LLA coordinates and Euler angles (orientation) of a phone, where alpha = beta = gamma = 0 when the top of the phone is pointing north and facing up, I would like to find the unit ENU coordinates of where the camera is pointing.

Is there any resource or equations that can be helpful?

Edit:
I would provide additional context below.

1. I am trying to use the phone to find the TRUE direction (in 3d space) of an airplane, acting as a radar.
2. I already converted the LLA (latitude-longitude-altitude) coordinates of the phone and the target airplane into ECEF (Earth-centered, Earth-fixed) coordinates, and got the 3d vector by subtracting the two.
3. I also converted the directional vector into ENU (East-north-up) coordinates, with the origin at the phone's coordinates.
4. The final step is to compare the phone's orientation to the resulting ENU coordinates, so we can give it a score as to how far away is from directly pointing the phone camera to the target airplane.

However, I am still unable to find an equation or formula that can convert the Euler angles produced by the phone's orientation sensors.
The details of the orientation sensors are mentioned above.